# How do Setter and Getter methods work?

Tags: c#

Before I started encapsulation and learn how to use properties, I was looking at Setters and Getters methods.
I understood how `SetID` and `GetID` methods works but I wasn't sure about `SetName`, `GetName` and `GetPassMark` methods.

```
using System;

public class Student
{
    private int _id;                                      
    private string _Name;
    private int _PassMark = 35;

    public void SetId(int Id)      
    {
        if (Id<=0)                    
        {
            throw new Exception("Student Id cannot be negative");  
        }
        this._id = Id;      
    }

    public int GetId()                    
    {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void SetName(string Name)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))      
        {
            throw new Exception("Name cannot be null or empty");
        }
        this._Name = Name;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._Name))   
        {
            return "No Name";
        }
        else
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
    }

    public int GetPassMark()
    {
        return this._PassMark;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()                                                               
    {
        Student C1 = new Student();                                                                       
        C1.SetId(101);                
        C1.SetName("Mark");           

        Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}" , C1.GetId());
        Console.WriteLine("Student Name = {0}", C1.GetName());       
        Console.WriteLine("PassMark = {0}", C1.GetPassMark());

    }
}
```

When I looked at `SetName`, I understood that if the string is either empty or null, we throw exception and otherwise `this._Name = Name`.
But when I looked at `GetName`, I didn't really understand why there is the if statement.
If Name was null or empty, there wouldn't have been `this._Name` as we throw exception in `SetName`.
Can't we just write down `return this._Name` in GetName?
Also in `GetPassMark` method why is `this.` necessary in `return this._PassMark`?

Comment: It looks like you came from Java. If you use peoperties, you can implement automatic properties without having to create special getters and setters.

Comment: [C# Properties](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `_Name` is not being set when you are creating the object. So there is a possibility that a `Student` object will have `null` `_Name`. You can fix it by setting the `_Name` in the constructor, then you can just return it.

Many people prefer to use `this` even when it's not really necessary since it makes the code more obvious. It's just a syntactical preference.